# How to realtime update inbox notification by expressjs/ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm working on a project using express.js and ejs, there will be a header contains a inbox notification icon in top of the page, and I would like to notify user realtime the count of message(just like something like stackoverflow's inbox notification). How can I do that?

Comment: Many ways to implement. Alternatively, you can use a web sockets. For example `soket.io`. A good tutorial here: https://codeforgeek.com/2015/09/real-time-notification-system-using-socket-io/